# $Li(x)$ function and Bell polynomials

Tags: number-theory, bell-numbers

I found one formula connecting the logarithmic integral function, $li(x)$, to polynomials as following:

$$li(x) = \frac{x}{\ln(x)} + \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{P_k(\ln(x))}{x^k}$$

where $P_k(x)$ is the $k^{th}$ Bell polynomial, which is a polynomial in $x$ that arises in the study of combinatorics and number theory.

This formula expresses $li(x)$ as a sum of terms involving powers of $\frac{1}{x}$ and polynomials in $\ln(x)$. The first term, $\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$, is the main term of the expansion, and it dominates the behavior of $li(x)$ as x becomes large. The remaining terms, which involve the Bell polynomials, represent "corrections" to the main term that become increasingly small as $x$ increases.

The Bell series expansion of $li(x)$ is a useful tool in the analysis of prime numbers.

My question is simple: if $P_k(x)$ refers to the $k^{th}$ Bell polynomial, then $x$ must be an integer. Nevertheless here we have ${P_k(\ln(x))}$.
I'm looking for the conditions for $x$ when we define a function f derived from the formula above:

$$f_k(x)=\frac{x}{\ln(x)}+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{P_k(\ln(x))}{x^k} = li(x)$$

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question: in $P_k(x)$ or $P_k(\ln x)$, the subscript $k$ must be an integer, but there's no problem when the argument $x$ or $\ln x$ is any real number (these are just polynomials after all).

Comment: Ok. Good answer. Thanks. I've just discovered these polynomials.